# Mysterious status 11 errors on Hyper-V servers

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v

I've noticed quite a few of our Hyper-V servers (both 2008 and 2012) report the following error in the Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-Hypervisor/Operational log when they restart (and start all the VMs):

```
Source: Hyper-V-Hypervisor
EventID: 8451
Text: Hyper-V failed creating a new partition (status 11)!
```

The various MS blogs I've Googled say the Status 11 error is just a general error meaning a VM couldn't be started. However all the VMs are running just fine. I suspect this may be a ghost VM left behind when a VM was deleted because if I take an HV server with three guests, all running fine, the last four events in the log show (in order):

```
Hyper-V failed creating a new partition (status 11)!
Hyper-V successfully created a new partition (partition 2).
Hyper-V successfully created a new partition (partition 3).
Hyper-V successfully created a new partition (partition 4).
```

So my guess is that there is a stub *partition 1* left behind somewhere.

But I've looked and looked and cannot see any trace of an old *partition 1* that might be causing the problem. Can anyone suggest where this might be, or alternatively is there some other explanation that I've overlooked?

Comment: Can you check, if you have got unused scsi adapter in any of the vm (no harddisk attached) and if removing them help?

Comment: @bangal: I've just looked on my own personal HV server (which is one of the many that report the "status 11" error) and there are no VMs that have a SCSI controller with no VHD attached.

Comment: When all VMs are booted, how is the VHD storage utilization tracking? Is there enough free space on disk and in memory? Also double check your checkpoints; if they're on a separate volume make sure its space is good too.

Comment: @SmithPlatts: there is loads of free memory and disk. None of the VMs have any checkpoints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be a resource alocation error. You might have a lot of resources alocated to the VM's and when they are starting then Windows can not alocate those resources fast enough(error 11) then it continues to boot them up.To test this I would:

1. stop all the VM's
2. take them out for auto start
3. start them manually, while waiting 5-10 seconds before launching the next one
4. look for the logs if the error is back

Comment: Hmm, close. On my test HV server if I stop all the VMs then start them again there is no error, no matter whether I start them all together or one at a time. However, if I stop all the VMs, then restart the HV server, then start just one VM I get the error. It looks as if the error happens the very first time a VM is started after the HV server is rebooted, but then it doesn't happen again. Weird.

Comment: It happens when any of the three VMs is started after a reboot. One of the VMs has a lot of memory and disk while another is much smaller, so it doesn't seem to be related to the demands made by the VM. It looks as if after a restart the first attempt to start a VM fails then is retried and succeeds. That would explain why the log reports the first VM is partition 2.

Comment: It's a error from Hyper-V memory allocation, I've had VM's with Workstation and Hyper-V and only Hyper-V had the errors(or who knows maybe Hyper-V reports them). You could probably see this with process explorer or with SysInternals, interpretation will take some effort.

Comment: Thanks Alex. The error is obviously benign so I think the appropriate strategy is to just ignore it.